# Firebase phone verification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I am new to android studio development and I follow a youtube tutorial. I follow the code but when I run the app my phone verification failed. I am from Philippines and currently using +63 code on my phone number but it failed to authenticate to firebase database. Please help and here is the code...

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PhoneLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button SendVerificationCodeButton, VerifyButton;
    private EditText InputPhoneNumber, InputVerificationCode;

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private String mVerificationId;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        SendVerificationCodeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_ver_code_button);
        VerifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify_button);
        InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number_input);
        InputVerificationCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.verification_code_input);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


        SendVerificationCodeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String phoneNumber = InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)){
                    Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Please enter your phone number first...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    loadingBar.setTitle("Phone Verification");
                    loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while we are authenticating your phone...");
                    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    loadingBar.show();

                    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                            60,                 // Timeout duration
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                            PhoneLoginActivity.this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                            callbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                }
            }
        });

        VerifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendVerificationCodeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                InputPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                String verificationCode = InputVerificationCode.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(verificationCode)){
                    Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Please write the verification code first...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    loadingBar.setTitle("Verification Code");
                    loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait while verifying code...");
                    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    loadingBar.show();
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, verificationCode);
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                }
            }
        });

        callbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Invalid phone number, please enter correct phone number with your country code" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                SendVerificationCodeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                InputPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                VerifyButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                InputVerificationCode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                                   @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;

                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Code has been sent, please check and verify...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                SendVerificationCodeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                InputPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                VerifyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                InputVerificationCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        };
    }
    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Congratulations, you're logged in succcessfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SendUserToMainActivity();
                        } else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Error :" +message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(PhoneLoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class
        );
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific line of your code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, here sir.. Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Invalid phone number, please enter correct phone number with your country code" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); , my app will display this message even though I formatted my phone number according to my country code.. ex: +639000000000..in that format when I inputted it on the EditText..

Comment: There's an exception passed to that method. What does `e.toString()` show you?